# bivariate density function - components are not independent

Tags: probability, statistics

I want to show that the random variables of the density function

$$\begin{cases}π^{−1} & :\textsf{if }x^2 + y^2 < 1\\0 & :\textsf{elsewhere}\end{cases}$$
... is dependent.

However, I therefore want to use the rule $\mathsf P(A ∩ B) = 0$

I am not quite sure if I calculated it right. I calculated the marginal density of X and Y:

for X: $2\cdot (1-y^2)^{1/2} \cdot 1/π$

for Y: $2\cdot (1-x^2)^{1/2} \cdot 1/π$

and then simply multiplied these two and as they were not the same as the given density function it is therefore not dependent.

I am not sure if I could really use such a simple calculation like multiplying or if there is something else I did not consider because I am not quite sure how to consider the probabilities in this case.

Comment: Yes the approach is alright. You just need to find a pair $(x,y)$ such that $f_{X,Y}(x,y)\neq f_X(x)f_Y(y)$ then it would be sufficient. As the support is not rectangular, you can even make use of the fact without calculating the marginal. E.g. $\Pr\{X > 0.75, Y > 0.75\} = 0$ but $\Pr\{X > 0.75\} = \Pr\{Y > 0.75\} > 0$.

Comment: Indeed.  You *do not* require $\mathsf P(A\cap B)=0$ *in general*, but finding a particular region where it does is good.

Answer (score 1):

Your procedure is fine. Alternately, let $A$ be the event $0.9\le X\le 1$, and let $B$ be the event $0.9\le Y\le 1$. It is clear that $\Pr(A)\ne 0$ and  $\Pr(B)\ne 0$, but $\Pr(A\cap B)=0$. So $\Pr(A\cap B)\ne \Pr(A)\Pr(B)$, and therefore $X$ and $Y$ are not independent.